# How to avoid Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing(CORS) while using axios in Vuejs?

Tags: java, web-services, vuejs2, axios

I have developed a web application using Vue js. I am using axios for making API calls. And I am using Web services for API. I have included CORS filter in my API for ‘Allow-Control-Allow-origin’.
I have used axios like this:

```
axios.get('http://192.26.3.51:8097/FeedbackPhase2/login) .then(response => { this.fb1 = response.data this.vh = this.fb1.length })
```

And in my CORS filter:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

The problem is, when I load the page in different browsers, I am getting an Error like this:

```
Failed to load http://192.26.3.51:8097/FeedbackPhase2/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (webpack-internal:///179:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///178:87)
```

What should I do? Please guide me.

Comment: What do you get if you use `fetch('http://192.26.3.51:8097/FeedbackPhase2/login', {mode: 'cors',}) .then(response => { this.fb1 = response.data this.vh = this.fb1.length });` instead?

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", with same "Failed to load http://192.26.3.51:8097/FeedbackPhase2/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."